# No initWithAppId method in the new facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing Facebook iOS application. The problem I encountered that there is no method `initWithAppID`, only `initWithAppID andDelegate:`
But I don't want to specify the delegate while initializing the object, because I am doing this in my appDelegate and `<FBRequestDelegate>` i.e. will be implemented in my UIView subclass.

So my question: where is better to initialize Facebook object and what to set in `andDelegate:` ?

Would be grateful for the answer,

Artem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the methods on FBSessionDelegate are marked as optional so you should be able to pass nil as the delegate.

```
/**
 * Your application should implement this delegate to receive session callbacks.
 */
@protocol FBSessionDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

/**
 * Called when the user successfully logged in.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin;

/**
 * Called when the user dismissed the dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;

/**
 * Called when the user logged out.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout;

@end
```

The Facebook class has the delegate as an assigned property, so you can set it later on.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<FBSessionDelegate> sessionDelegate;
```